# How can I sort lines and extract information in Python?

Tags: python

I have this file text:

```
<< end of ENERGY.
iupac_m_486_> OE1/2 will be swapped:     -136.1396        1     1
openf___224_> Open           Dominio1.BL00100001.pdb
wrpdb___568_> Residues, atoms, selected atoms:      268     2115     2115

>> Summary of successfully produced loop models:
Filename                          molpdf
----------------------------------------
Dominio1.BL00010001.pdb         24.69530
Dominio1.BL00020001.pdb         14.33748
Dominio1.BL00030001.pdb         30.53454
Dominio1.BL00040001.pdb         23.82516
Dominio1.BL00050001.pdb         27.48684
Dominio1.BL00060001.pdb         18.17364
Dominio1.BL00070001.pdb         30.98407
Dominio1.BL00080001.pdb         17.19927
Dominio1.BL00090001.pdb         19.02460
Dominio1.BL00100001.pdb         22.57086
```

I want sort the last 10 lines and find which file name is associated with the smallest number, to use it in the second part of my script.

In the example file above, the file name I want is `Dominio1.BL00020001.pdb`, because it's associated with the smallest number, but I want to find it programmatically.

This code just show the lines that I need sort

```
import itertools
with open('%s'%W, "r") as text_file:
    for line in itertools.islice(text_file, 2210, 2220):
        print line
CREATE CODE..(please Can somebody help me to do it?)
```

and find that the `Dominio1.BL00020001.pdb` has the smallest number and continue reading and put it like "a", I can't use like this:

```
model_initial= '%s'%a'
```

Comment: Basically, you need to replace *"CODE ..bla bla bla bla"* with **some actual Python code**, then run it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I sort lines and select some characters of it, of a text file in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200719/how-can-i-sort-lines-and-select-some-characters-of-it-of-a-text-file-in-python)

Comment: I need to create a CODE of python, in the last question, I can't delete it cause have answers, and it's wrong. Please help me friends.

Comment: What went wrong in the last question?

Comment: Duplicate question:
 http://stackoverflow.com/q/28200719/584846

Comment: @TereHs it is completely unclear what your problem is. This isn't a code-writing service; where is **your code**, and what precisely is wrong with it? Rather than opening a new question, **edit the previous one**; don't just keep asking the same thing over and over again without adding any useful information or making an attempt to **actually write it yourself**.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes, sorry for no put it, but I dont have idea how can i do it. I'm Begginner in python, sorry. I just want a few help. Thanks

Comment: If you have no idea how to do this in code, I suggest you open your file in Excel, split on whitespace and sort the column with the values you're interested in.

Comment: @TereHs Again, *this isn't a code-writing service*. We also don't provide tutoring - if you're a beginner, find a tutorial and follow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function below will be used when we have an *interesting* line.

We want to clean the line, stripping white space on its sides, and split it in two parts, the file name and the associated value.

This is not enough, because what we want to do next is to sort numerically, so we convert the number string to a float and return a tuple composed by the float and the file name.

```
def float_name(line):
    fname, number = line.strip().split()
    return float(number), fname
```

Building on the function above, we write a function to process the data (note that data is just an iterable that contains strings, possibly a list or a file object).

Using a *list comprehension*, we scan the data and if the current line `l` begins with the required key, `initial`, we deem it interesting and pass it to `float_name`. The resulting list of tuples is then sorted, and the sorted list is returned to the caller.

```
def sort_floats_names(data,initial):
     floats_names = [float_name(l) for l in data if l.startswith(initial)]
     floats_names.sort()
     return floats_names
```

It's now time to put our functions at work,

```
sorted_floats_names = sort_floats_names(open('your_data.txt'), 'Dominio1')
model_initial = sorted_floats_names[0][1]
```

the first line builds a sorted list of `(float, fname)` tuples, the second line assign the name `model_initial` to the file name component of the zero-th tuple in the sorted list.

*Addendum:*  all the code above as an one-liner

```
In [31]: sorted([(float(nb),fn) for fn,nb in [l.split() for l in data if l.startswith('Dominio1')]])[0][1]
Out[31]: 'Dominio1.BL00020001.pdb'
```

Comment: This solution uses memory proportional to the number of matching lines in the input. If that's a huge number, please see my solution, which uses memory only for 1 line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import re
def yield_items(filename):
  with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
      if re.match(r'\S+[.]pdb\s+(\d[\d.]+)(?:\s|\Z)', line):
        items = line.split()
        yield float(items[1]), items[0]
print min(yield_items('input.txt'))
```

In contrast to the solutions of gboffi and Malik Brahimi, this solution uses less memory: it uses memory only for 1 line at a time, so even if the file contains a huge number of matching lines, this solution doesn't keep more than 1 of them in memory at the same time.

Comment: Shouldn't you `close()` the file? Also, wouldnt it be better to use `with open()`?

Comment: Yes, the result is that I want it, but, the result is about the .pdb that has highest number, how can I do, for have the .pdb that has smallest number? How can I change in the code? Thanks

Comment: @TereHs If i understand correctly, you like this code, but problem is it gives the `max`. Instead you want the minumum. If so, just change `max` to `min` in the code above.

Comment: Thanks friend, your answer is good too, but I just can choose one.

Comment: Added `with open(`, changed `max` to `min` as suggested. Also added a sentence about the low memory requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use Python `re`.

`file.txt`

```
Dominio1.BL00010001.pdb         24.69530
Dominio1.BL00020001.pdb         14.33748
Dominio1.BL00030001.pdb         30.53454
Dominio1.BL00040001.pdb         23.82516
Dominio1.BL00050001.pdb         27.48684
Dominio1.BL00060001.pdb         18.17364
Dominio1.BL00070001.pdb         30.98407
Dominio1.BL00080001.pdb         17.19927
Dominio1.BL00090001.pdb         19.02460
Dominio1.BL00100001.pdb         22.57086
```

`sorts.py`

```
import re

lines = open('file.txt').readlines() # readlines
lines = [i.strip() for i in lines] # remove newlines

lines = [re.sub('\s+', ' ', i) for i in lines] # remove extra spaces
lines = [i.split(' ') for i in lines] # split by space
lines = sorted(lines, key = lambda i: float(i[1])) # sort by id

print lines[0][0] # print item with least id
```

Comment: I can't get the result correct, in the file text this lines have the 2211 to 2220 number line. How can I select it and do it this?

Comment: What are you talking about? Copy the post as is.

Comment: Yes, the text is above in this page. Are the last 10 lines, that have the 2211-2220 number lines.

Comment: Yes write the file with only the last ten lines. Didn't see that you edited your question.